# trying to sign up for Paypal sandbox - testing Paypal buttons

Tags: testing, button, paypal

It seems I'm having the same problems people had 4 years ago in working in Paypal's sandbox - I keep getting the message to log in, when I do, it says my info is not correct. Has anyone determined a current work-around to testing Paypal buttons? My client is set up to send out emails with links to the pdf's her clients have bought, but no one seems to have gotten that email. So I need an effective way to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you resetting the password of your sandbox test account, or even simply create a new test account in PayPal's developer site to get thru. Details could be checked at

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/